# is this expression "think big and take risk rather than think small and take safe" ok?

Tags: word-choice

I want to express this sentence

> Should young people think big and take risk rather than think small and take safe?

So, *think big* >< *think small* & *take risk* >< *take safe*

So, is the above question ok or not ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase *take safe* doesn't exist in English. A common idiom is *play it safe*.

Answer (score 0):

No, in this sense "safe" is an adjective as in "the **safe** choice."  You need a noun to serve as the direct object of "take."  The nominal form of "safe" is "safety," but "take safety" isn't idiomatic.  Two suggestions to keep the parallelism and the cadence:

> Should young people think big and take risk rather than think small
>   and **seek safety**?
>   Should young people think big and take risk rather
>   than think small and **take refuge**?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "take risks" as well? The "think big" vs "think small" works, but not "take risks" vs "seek safety" or "take refuge". I'd say "*make safe bets*".

Comment: Cyberseaches find the usage "take risks" far outnumbers "take risk," but the latter as a non-countable collective does appear.  As a rhetorical question, I think the flow works better with two collectives.  YMMV.

Comment: As an uncountable noun, then it ought to be phrased as "take some risk" but as you say YMMV.